# "+" removed from string sent to server (Objective-C to PHP server)

Tags: php, ios7

I have a base64 string (for an in app iOS purchase) and trying to send it to my PHP server so it can validate with apple.

Problem is the string sent is not the string recieved. All the "+" marks inside my string are removed. How can I preserve my string just as it is in the client so my PHP server gets it raw.

Here is my client code

```
NSDictionary* post = @{@"receipt":[receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]};
//combines my post with an endpoint inside _post

   for (NSString* k in _post)
       {
           NSLog(@"%@ & %@",k,_post[k]);
           postDataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@=%@", postDataStr,k,_post[k]];
       }
   _req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_url cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:15.0f];
   [_req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [_req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [_req setHTTPBody:[postDataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   _data = [NSMutableData data];

   [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:_req delegate:self];
```

And on my server its this

$appleReturnedReceipt = $this->getReceiptData($_REQUEST['receipt'], $_REQUEST['sandbox']);

When I trace out the string before and after the server touches it, all the "+" symbols are missing.

Any and all advice appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the kind answer below doing this fixed the issue:

```
NSString* newPost = [(NSString*)_post[k] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Comment: its treated as a space. try replacing it with %2B

Comment: HOLY *&*(*( COW IT WORKED!!!!! WOW THIS TOOK ME DAYS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is called "URL encoding". Actually in your POST request you tell the server that you send URL encoded data, but you don't. Instead of only replacing "+" with "%2B", you should apply URL encoding to the whole string - I'm pretty sure Objective-C has a class/function to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should url encode the values you want to send.